# After converting field to tag, no query result

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, telemetry

I am using Telegraf with Telemetry, I want to see traffic level on interface based on their description, "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description". Unfortunately the interface description was as field key, which I converted using the processors.converter. Since I needed to rewrite the data after this, I just dropped the whole measurement so the new tag can take place.

I do see the descriptions as tag fields and I do see the interface description as a tag key.

Unfortunately I am still getting blank results on any query when I try with querying by interface description.

```
### Relevant telegraf.conf:
 # Convert values to another metric value type
[[processors.converter]]
# Fields to convert
[processors.converter.fields]
tag = ["/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description"]
```

#### System info:

Telegraf 1.14.5
Debian

#### Steps to reproduce:

```
> select "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description" from "/interfaces/"
```

(empty result) this is expected since now its a tag

```
> show tag keys
name: /interfaces/
tagKey
------
/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description
```

we can see here that now it's as a tag key

```
> show tag values with key = "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description"
```

(gives all descriptions)

```
> SELECT "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/counters/out-pkts" from /interfaces/ where "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description" = 'some_description'
```

(empty result) Where I would like to have some result based on the interface description

#### Expected behavior:

```
SELECT "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/counters/out-pkts" from /interfaces/ where "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description" = 'some_description'
```

to give some a result for the interface with that description

#### Actual behavior:

```
SELECT "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/counters/out-pkts" from /interfaces/ where "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description" = 'some_description'
```

(is not returning any result)

#### Additional information

I am also using Chronograph which gives no results too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just select just a tag from a measurement. For influx to return results it needs atleast one field in the select clause.

Comment: SELECT "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/counters/out-pkts" from /interfaces/ where "/interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description" = 'some_description'

isn't this that query? so the out-pkts is a field /interface/ measurement and /interfaces/interface/subinterfaces/subinterface/state/description is tag.